# Stepper motor continues turning after code is finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am playing around with a Nema17 stepper motor on an Raspberry Pi 4 using Python 3.7.3 and a A4988 stepper motor driver. I run the code below and it works fine however after the code is finished, the stepper motor continues to turn in a somewhat sporatic fashion. How do I get it to just stop after it finishes the code? I have included the code I am using below.

````
# import the library
from RpiMotorLib import RpiMotorLib

#define GPIO pins
GPIO_pins = (17, 27, 22) # Microstep Resolution MS1-MS3 -> GPIO Pin
direction= 24       # Direction -> GPIO Pin
step = 23      # Step -> GPIO Pin

# Declare an named instance of class pass GPIO pins numbers
mymotortest = RpiMotorLib.A4988Nema(direction, step, GPIO_pins, "A4988")


# call the function, pass the arguments
mymotortest.motor_go(False, "Half" , 500, .001, False, .05)

# good practise to cleanup GPIO at some point before exit
GPIO.cleanup()```

P.S I was wondering what would be the best library or way to control a stepper motor? As in, is this the best library to be using or are there better and more precise methods in doing so.

Thank you
````

Comment: Suggesting libs is off-topic for SO. What you should do is explicitly STOP the motor _before_ "cleaning up" the GPIOs. Those two may but do not seem to be the same thing. You may also need to review the cleanup process. It may have to be changed, so it does not unpurposely send movement commands to the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe GPIO.cleanup puts the gpio outputs in an undefined, floating state.
Try put the A4988 in sleep mode before GPIO.cleanup. [A4988 pdf](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J450/A4988.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I read through some of the PDF on the SLEEP, ENABLE and RESET pins and that has given me some more hope. I'll try that today

Comment: I have been looking at the RpiMotorLib.A4988Nema source you're using. Odd, but it has no stop function. Maybe you can add your own 'def stop(self):' function.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the problem with A4988 on Pi Model 4B v1.4. **Mace** is right, the problem comes from GPIO.cleanup().
For example, removing the GPIO.cleanup() line in the A4988_Nema_Test.py script found on the [github](https://github.com/gavinlyonsrepo/RpiMotorLib/blob/master/test/A4988_Nema_Test.py) solved this issue in my case.